# Xamarin - Connect to Remote Mac on network

Tags: macos, xamarin

I am trying to connect my Visual Studio to Mac for builds on my mac for ios builds. I get the following error

Couldn't retrieve SSH Fingerprint. Please ensure the Mac is reachable and Remote Login is enabled.

Comment: did you try to do both of the things it suggested?